# jQuery autocomplete with jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, autocomplete, pug

I'm trying to get an input box to autocomplete results from a javascript array. The input box shows up but I'm not seeing any recommended autocompletes. I know that the array is being passed properly because I tested an each loop to create a list of the elements.

I'm open to alternatives to jQuery, it just seems to be a simple autocomplete for this purpose. I'd appreciate any possible fixes to this problem.

Here's what I have so far:

**js**

```
res.render('index', {arrayName: title});
```

**index.jade**

```
//jquery includes...    
.ui-widget
  label(for="tags") Tags:
  input(id="tags")
script.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var list = #{arrayName};
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source:list,
      autofocus:true,
      delay:300,
      minLength:2
    });
  });
```

Comment: so does data structure match the plugin docs?

Comment: In the documentation they used a string array, which is what I'm using

Comment: and you included appropriate css? There is another object format also for data

Comment: I have the smoothness css, jquery js, and jquery-ui js

Comment: ive got same issue, is this has been resolved ? @user147910

Comment: Hi, @user147910 , i solved the problem. Please refer to my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907373/jquery-autocomplete-with-jade-pug/52908569#52908569